# How does one compute a resultant by using Euclidean algorithm?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

In an answer to the question [Resultant of Two Univariate Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569578/resultant-of-two-univariate-polynomials), a PDF of course slides was linked which describes a modification of Euclid's algorithm for computing univariate polynomial resultants (reference: http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~eschost/publications/CS829-lecture3.pdf - slide 53).

The algorithm is as follows (with F, G the input polynomials, d_i the degree of F_i, and LC(p) the leading coefficient of p):

```
F_1 := F
F_2 := G
i := 2
R_1 := 1

while deg(F_i) > 0:
   F_{i+1} := F_{i-1} mod F_i
   R_i := (-1)^{d_i * d_{i-1}} * LC(F_i)^{d_{i-1} - d_i} * R_{i-1}
   i++

if F_i != 0 then return R_{i-1} * LC(F_i)^{d_{i-1}}
   else return 0
```

However, this algorithm is incorrect, though I am not sure `where' the bug is.

To see that it is incorrect, consider the following two polynomials in Q[x]:

```
f(x) = x^2 - 2x - 1,
g(x) = x^2 - 3.
```

Then, the algorithm given above computes that

```
Resultant(f,g) = 4
```

whereas the correct result is

```
Resultant(f,g) = -8.
```

This correct result is easily verified e.g. via Sage:

```
sage: x, = QQ['x'].gens()
sage: f = x^2 - 2*x - 1
sage: g = x^2 - 3
sage: f.resultant(g)
-8
```

Where is the bug in the resultant algorithm given in those slides? Or, alternatively, what is a correct modification of Euclid's algorithm sufficient for computing the resultant of two univariate polynomials in Q[x]? Please note that I am not looking for methods based on subresultant PRS's, but rather for a `simple' modification of Euclid's algorithm sufficient for computing the resultant of two univariate polynomials. (Of course, the resulting method will be far less efficient than subresultant-based methods. On the other hand, it should be much easier to understand, implement and teach.)

Thank you.

Comment: The usual name is "sub-resultant algorithm". Wikipedia has an extensive description.

Comment: Hi, Lutz - Thank you for your comment. However, the subresultant algorithm is far more complicated than what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a simple modification of Euclid's algorithm which correctly computes the resultant of two univariate polynomials. Of course, subresultant-based methods will be far more efficient than such a simple modification of Euclid's algorithm. But, efficiency is not my concern at the moment.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I saw too late that you stated that your computation is in $\Bbb Q[X]$.

Comment: Euclidean algorithm based computation of resultants is discussed in detail in [Subresultants Revisited by Gathen and Lücking](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397502006394). They appear to be Schost's source (Schost is the author of the linked notes). It is a shame that most texts only discuss Sylvester's (occasionally also Bezout's) giant determinants for computing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slide 49 bottom has the basis of the algorithm

> Corollary: For $F$, $G$ with coefficients in a field,
>   $$\text{res}(F, G) = (−1)^{\deg(F ) \deg(G)}\text{ LeadCoeff}(G)^{\deg(F )−\deg(R)}\,\text{res}(G, R),$$
>   for $R$ such that $F = QG + R$.

---

Following that theorem and the algorithm, the example computes as
\begin{align}
\text{res}(x^2 - 2x - 1, x^2 - 3)
&=(-1)^{2\cdot 2}\,1^{2-1}\,\text{res}(x^2 - 3, -2x+2)\\
&=(-1)^{2\cdot 1}\,(-2)^{2-0}\,\text{res}(-2x+2, -2)\\
&=4\cdot(-2)=-8
\end{align}

which you found as the correct result. <s>So there is nothing wrong with the algorithm.</s> The difference $\deg(F )−\deg(R)$ is not correctly translated into the terms of the algorithm, it should be $d_{i-1}-d_{i+1}$.

---

To get a feeling for the reduction formula, let's recompute it (under the simplifying assumption that $G$ has simple roots).
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}(F,G)
&=(-1)^{\deg F⋅\deg G}⋅\operatorname{Res}(G,F)\\
&=(-1)^{\deg F⋅\deg G}⋅\operatorname{LC}(G)^{\deg F}⋅\prod_{z:G(z)=0}F(z)\\
&=(-1)^{\deg F⋅\deg G}⋅\operatorname{LC}(G)^{\deg F}⋅\prod_{z:G(z)=0}(Q(z)G(z)+R(z))\\
&=(-1)^{\deg F⋅\deg G}⋅\operatorname{LC}(G)^{\deg F-\deg R}⋅\operatorname{LC}(G)^{\deg R}⋅\prod_{z:G(z)=0}R(z)\\
&=(-1)^{\deg F⋅\deg G}⋅\operatorname{LC}(G)^{\deg F-\deg R}⋅\operatorname{Res}(G,R)
\end{align}

Comment: Hi, Lutz. Thank you for this helpful answer. Will you please explain how you get (-2)^{2-0} in the second line of the sequence of equations? Here, I compute (-2)^{2-1), as the algorithm calls for (-2)^(d_{i-1} - d_i}), which in this case (with i=3) we have F_2 = x^2 - 3 and F_3 = -2x + 2. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a discrepancy between the corollary where $\deg F-\deg R$ would translate into $\deg F_{i-1}-\deg F_{i+1}=d_{i+1}-d_{i-1}$ and the algorithm. I'll withdraw the last sentence of the answer.

Comment: Excellent - Now I understand. Thank you very much!